# How can I assign values to an array in a constructor using Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Here is what I have tried:

```
class PhraseService

    phrasePosShortNames: [{ id: number, name: string }];
    phrasePosNames = [
    {
        id: 0,
        longName: '#',
        shortName: '#'
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        longName: 'Noun',
        shortName: '#'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        longName: 'Verb',
        shortName: 'V'
    }
    ];
    constructor( ) {

        this.phrasePosShortNames = this.phrasePosNames.map(item => {
            id: item.id,
            name: item.longName
        })
    }
```

But this gives me an error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error TS2322  Type 'void[]' is not assignable to type '[{ id: number;
>   name: string; }]'.   Property '0' is missing in type 'void[]'

Can  someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
this.phrasePosNames.map(item => {
    return {
      id: item.id,
      name: item.longName
    };
});
```

And the type should be

```
{ id: number, name: string }[]
```

or

```
Array<{ id: number, name: string }>
```

I would define an interface instead, which would make the code more readable.

Comment: Thanks. My mistake there but I still get a typescript error: error TS2322: Build: Type '{ id: number; name: string; }[]' is not assignable to type '[{ id: number; name: string; }]'.

Comment: Fixed with my definition by adding [] to the end of the { ... }